# how to create a form validation which states that input value shouldn't be empty and it should be > 0?

Tags: validation, input, label, submit, react-forms

I want to make a logic before submitting which states that input value shouldn't be any empty value and it should be greater than 0.

```
    <Form className  = "workout-form">
     <div className ="form-row">
              <label className ="form__label" value>Duration</label>
              <input type = 'number' value = {duration} min = '0' onChange = {(e) => setDuration(e.target.value)} class = 'duration' placeholder="min" required/>
            </div>
 <button className ="form-btn" onClick = {submitWorkout}>Add Workout</button>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is to create a form validation function that will be called when we want to submit the form, and when the form is correctly completed, you then call the function to submit the form informations.
An example of the form control function

```
function formValidation(){
    duration = document.getElementById('durationField').value;
    
    if(duration > 0 && duration != ""){
         //call the submit function
         //submitWorkout()
    }

}

//function to submit the form
function submitWorkout(){
    //content of the function
}
```

For this to work you have to add the id property to your input field and set it to durationField as follow:

```
<input type = 'number' id='durationField' value = {duration} min = '0' onChange = {(e) => setDuration(e.target.value)} class = 'duration' placeholder="min" required/>
```